# How to host images stored inside S3 static website, over HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket which I'm using for storing images uploaded by users. Then I save paths to those images in my database, each path looks like so https://bucket-name.s3.eu-central-1...

I then added an image resizing feature which requires the S3 bucket to be a static website, so that redirection rules can be used.
Appearantly this static website thingy made it impossible to download those pictures using old paths with https protocol, and because my website is using https - I can't make http requests. So now all the profile pictures of the users aren't displayed at all.

I'm looking for a solution to this problem. I can change pictures' paths stored in the database if needed.

---

One possible solution I have in mind is using a subdomain with CloudFront, e.g. `pictures.my-website.com/name-of-the-picture.png`

Do you think it'll work and it's a good solution, or there is a better way?

Comment: Are your user's access to their own uploaded files authenticated? Or have you made the images public and are relying on unauthenticated users not knowing the URLs? If the latter, you may want to rethink that.

Comment: The access isn't authenticated, and anyone with URL can access those pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Use CloudFront as a server with predefined domain and SSL certificates https://medium.com/@tsubasakondo_36683/serve-images-with-cloudfront-s3-8691d5c387b6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).